# Existence of 2D Quasicrystal with vertex having only even (or odd) coordination number.

Tags: graphing-functions, tiling, quasiperiodic-function

The coordination number for a vertex is the number of links connected to it.
In the Penrose lattice, it takes range from 3 to 7.  However, the mean coordination number is 4, the same as a square lattice.

[image: Penrose coordination number]

For Ammann-Beenker quasicrystal, coordination number takes value in range 3-8, and interestingly it's mean is the same as the coordination number of the square and Penrose lattice.

[image: Ammann-Beenker coordination number]

The same story also applies to generalized Rauzy tiling. The coordination number change between 3-5 with a mean equal to 4!

[image]

We can see all of them have a continuous distribution of coordination numbers.
I am curious to know is there any quasicrystal in 2D with, for example, only even (or odd) coordination number?

Comment: Which definition are you using for quasicrystal? Just an FLC repetitive tiling? If so, you can obviously increase the mean valence of the vertices by cutting tiles in half. This would break the cut and project structure though.

Comment: @DanRust Thank you. You are right, by breaking bipartite properties of these repetitive quasicrystals, we can get even (or odd) coordination number for any vertexes.  However, is there any possibility to have a bipartite version?

Comment: I try several times to break the tilings in Penrose lattice. However, it seems after that, we have a mixture of odd and even coordination numbers.  So, I think my question is not so trivial!

Comment: related in Matter Modeling SE: [Proposing a 2D quasicrystal; what are the necessary and sufficient conditions? (If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, or...?)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6993/201) and here in Math SE: [What is 12-fold Stampfli-inflation tiling and where/how can I recognize it in this analysis of dodecagonal 30° twisted bilayer graphene quasicrystal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4412856/284619) where *any help or insight* will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @DanRust I've just added a bounty

Comment: @uhoh, Actually Penrose and Ammann-Beenker center models have only even coordination numbers.  The Center model is given when you put vertex inside tiles and connect them if they have a common edge.

Comment: @uhoh, Also If we use a version of Penrose tiling with triangles, its center model gives a lattice with only an odd coordination number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be an answer regarding existence. Yes, there is a systematic way to make a tiling with only odd or even coordination numbers.
The strategy uses the center model.

**For even coordinated tilings:**

1. First find the tiling with parallelogram tiles.
2. Put a vertex inside each tile
   [image]
3. Connect these vertices if their corresponding tiles have common
   edges.
   [image]

**For odd coordinated tiling**

1. triangulate (connect vertices in a way to all tiles become a triangles without overlap) the tiling by respecting quasiperiodicity (for instance use inflation rules).
2. Put a vertex inside each tile
3. Connect these vertices if their corresponding tiles have common
   edges.